# Using DefaultStreamedContent returns net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING in some files

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

I'm trying to send a pdf file to be showed in the media pdf viewer. But every time i try to show files bigger then 500Kb it always returns this error.

```
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

The code i'm using is this.

**xhtml**

```
<p:media value="#{documentPreview.file}" height="800px" width="100%" player="pdf" cache="false">Your browser can't display pdf</p:media>
```

**bean**

```
public StreamedContent getFile ( ) throws IOException {
    return new DefaultStreamedContent (new FileInputStream ( filepath + "indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf" ), "application/pdf" );
};
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work, the problem was my Kaspersky Anti-Virus not letting the files load.